# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl Crashes my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my viewController.m file

```
- (IBAction)defaultAction:(id)sender {
    SimpleViewController *simpleView = [[SimpleViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:simpleView animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)flipAction:(id)sender {
    SimpleViewController *simpleView = [[SimpleViewController alloc]init];
    [simpleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:simpleView animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)dissolveAction:(id)sender {
    SimpleViewController *simpleView = [[SimpleViewController alloc]init];
    [simpleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:simpleView animated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (IBAction)pageCurlAction:(id)sender {

    SimpleViewController *simpleView = [[SimpleViewController alloc]init];
    [simpleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentViewController:simpleView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I have another class SimpleViewController.There is a button action like this in this class.

```
- (IBAction)dismissMeAction:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My default, flip and dissolve button works well but when i click pageCurl my apps crashes. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` is a style that requires additional special configuration. Here is from Apple's doc:

> Declaration
>
> UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl 
>   Discussion
>
> When the view controller is presented, one corner of the current view
>   curls up to reveal the presented view underneath. On dismissal, the
>   curled up page unfurls itself back on top of the presented view. A
>   view controller presented using this transition is itself prevented
>   from presenting any additional view controllers. This transition style
>   is supported only if the parent view controller is presenting a
>   full-screen view and you use the UIModalPresentationFullScreen modal
>   presentation style. **Attempting to use a different form factor for the**
>   **parent view or a different presentation style triggers an exception**.

so you have to make sure your `self` view is a full-screen and add full-screen presentation style to `simpleView` as below

```c
- (IBAction)pageCurlAction:(id)sender {

    SimpleViewController *simpleView = [[SimpleViewController alloc]init];
    [simpleView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [simpleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentViewController:simpleView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: I have done that now. When i am clicking pageCurl it works and goes to the next page. But when i am clicking dismiss it comes back to the main page but the main page becomes curl...